# MYSQL multiply if?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum

I have a query that looks like this:

```php
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(ps_order_detail.product_weight) as total_provision, COUNT(ps_order_detail.id_order_detail) as antal_ordrar, ps_customer.firstname
                   FROM ps_order_detail 
                  JOIN ps_orders ON ps_order_detail.id_order = ps_orders.id_order
                  JOIN ps_order_history ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_history.id_order
                  JOIN ps_customer ON ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
                  WHERE MONTH(ps_order_history.date_add) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND (ps_order_history.id_order_state) = '4' OR (ps_order_history.id_order_state) = '13'
                  GROUP BY ps_orders.id_customer
                  ORDER BY SUM(ps_order_detail.product_weight) DESC
                  ");


//fetch tha data from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo '<font size="3">';
   echo " Namn: ".$row{'firstname'}. "";
   echo " Provision: ".$row{'total_provision'}. "";
   echo " Abonnemang: ".$row{'antal_ordrar'}. "";
   echo '<br>';
   echo '</font size>';
}
```

It works fine but what i wana do is if the result "antal_ordrar" is larger than say 50 i wana multiply the result "total_provision" with 1,2 (add an extra 20% to the result)

Im new on mysql and are kinda stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(ps_order_detail.product_weight) *
   IF( COUNT(ps_order_detail.id_order_detail) > 50, 1.2, 1 ) AS total_provision,
   COUNT(ps_order_detail.id_order_detail) AS antal_ordrar, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, wrap this in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
   -- use the if statement
   IF( antal_ordrar > 50, total_provision * 1.2, total_provision ),
   antal_ordrar,
   firstname
FROM
   -- create a subquery so you can reuse the data.
   ( SELECT SUM(ps_order_detail.product_weight) as total_provision, 
            COUNT(ps_order_detail.id_order_detail) as antal_ordrar, 
            ps_customer.firstname as firstname
      FROM ps_order_detail 
         -- are you sure you need this many joins?     
         JOIN ps_orders ON ps_order_detail.id_order = ps_orders.id_order
         JOIN ps_order_history ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_history.id_order
         JOIN ps_customer ON ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
         -- group by normally uses the 'having' keyword.
         WHERE MONTH(ps_order_history.date_add) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
            AND (ps_order_history.id_order_state) = '4' 
            OR (ps_order_history.id_order_state) = '13'
         GROUP BY ps_orders.id_customer
         ORDER BY SUM(ps_order_detail.product_weight) DESC ) 
    -- an alias for your subquery so you can treat it like a table.
    tbl;
```

Just noticed this. You're using braces when you mean brackets: `$row{'total_provision'}` should be `$row['total_provision']`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to select

```
if (antal_ordrar > 50, total_provision * 1.2, total_provision) as total_provision
```

Comment: Tnx ALOT for fast and quick directions all! Got it working with SELECT SUM(ps_order_detail.product_weight) * IF(COUNT(ps_order_detail.id_order_detail) > 50, 1.2, 1)
 as total_provision